# Firebase: though I'm setting Data, values are not reflecting lively in realtime database of firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

App configurations are done.

Rules for the data base are set as

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}


//declaration
var userDB: FIRDatabaseReference!
```

**In viewDidLoad()**

```
userDB = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
//for reference database
```

the action method is like below

```
@IBAction func next(_ sender: Any) {
        guard fullname.text != "",email.text != "",password.text != "" ,confirmPassword.text != "" else {
            return
        }
        if(password.text == confirmPassword.text)
        {
            FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: email.text!, password: password.text!, completion: { (user, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription )
                }
                if let error = error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }

                if let user = user {
                    print(user.uid)
                    let changeRequest = FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.profileChangeRequest()
                    changeRequest.displayName = self.fullname.text!
                    changeRequest.commitChanges(completion: nil)

                    let imageRef = self.userStorage.child("\(user.uid).jpg")

                    let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.uploadPictureImageview.image!, 0.5)

                    let uploadTask = imageRef.put(data!, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, err) in
                        if err != nil {
                            print(err!.localizedDescription)
                        }

                        imageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, er) in
                            if er != nil {
                                print(er!.localizedDescription)
                            }

                            print(url)
                            if let url = url {
                                print(url)
                                let userInfo: [String : String] = ["uid" : user.uid,
                                                                "full name" : self.fullname.text!,
                                                                "urlToImage" : url.absoluteString]

                                self.userDB.child("users").child(user.uid).setValue(userInfo)


                                let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "usersVC")

                                self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

                            }

                        })

                    })

                    uploadTask.resume()

                }

            })
        }
        else{
            print("Password didnot match")
        }
    }
```

the Dictionary type has changed from [String: Any] to [String : String]

Data is not saving in the Realtime database of firebase. Did I forget something ?

Comment: Have you authenticate?

Comment: yea @AndriySavran
Storage is updating lively

Comment: he has set the firebase rules such that he shouldn't even have to authenticate users. Have you tried changing your userInfo dictionary to `let userInfo: [String: String] = ...` ?  And are you positive that `self.fullname.text!` has a value? Also have you downloaded the GoogleService-Info.plist file from your Firebase project and added it to your Xcode project?

Comment: I have done all the validations @MikeG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to open a connection to a Firebase reference is like this...

```
 //declare the reference as an implicitly unwrapped optional
 var userDB: FIRDatabaseReference!

 //set the value of the reference in viewDidLoad
 override func viewDidLoad(){
     userDB = FIRDatabase().database().reference()
 }
```

If you are still having the same problem after doing what I've shown above, then perhaps you forgot to download the GoogleService-info.plist file from your Firebase project and add it to your Xcode project

Also make sure that `self.fullname.text!` has a value otherwise it won't work since Firebase won't take a `nil` value

**EDIT**

also in your AppDelegate.swift file, check to make sure that you call `FIRApp.configure()` . I believe you can call this is `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` or you can do ..

```
override init(){
   FIRApp.configure()
}
```

Comment: I have done all the validations @MikeG and GoogleService-info.plist is also added. I'm able to store my image in storage of firebase.

Comment: Ok how about try something very simple to see if it works. In `viewDidLoad()` just try to write something to the database like... `userDB.child("users").setValue("TESTING")` and see if that works

Comment: hey buddy...working here. What could be my mistake @MikeG

Comment: What I showed in my previous comment worked for you? Then perhaps you need to declare the `userInfo` dictionary as `let userInfo: [String: String] = ...`  . Try that

Comment: If that doesn't work then could you please add the rest of your code

Comment: i have updated the whole code. [String: String] is also not working. @MikeG

Comment: What exactly did you determine was the problem?

Comment: Don't know for now. things are going fine now. :) thanks @MikeG